# Powershell script suddenly failing

Tags: powershell, csv

We have a script running daily on two separate servers, there have been no changes made to either copy of the script all year. Last weekend, there was a server outage that interrupted the script running on one of the servers, and ever since the script on that server partially fails each day.

Here is the code which continues to fail, I have broken it out and ran it locally without issue.

```
$rawlineCountFile ="C:\temp\files\test\linecount"
$rawlineCountFile = $rawlineCountFile +'RawlineCount' + 'test' + '.csv'
$filePath = "C:\temp\files\test"

# do line count in files

$bak = Get-ChildItem $filePath  | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".dat" } 

Try 
{ 

Write-Output  "line_count , file_name"
foreach ($file in $bak) { 

               $name = $file.name 
               $measure =(Get-Content $filePath\$file | Measure-Object)              
               $lines = $measure.Count                   
               Write-Output  "$lines , $name"  

               Write-Output "$lines , $name" >> $rawlineCountFile


                } 

} catch [Exception] {
  Write-Output $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
  Write-Output $_.Exception.Message 

    }
```

This script above looks at a folder with .dat files and FOR EACH one, it writes the $lines within each file ($measure.count) and the $file.name into a rawlinecountfile.csv.

i.e.

123 , file1.dat

234 , file2.dat

987 , file3.dat

567 , file4.dat

etc. etc.

Each day there are 7 files moved into this folder, then this script runs, so there should be 7 rows added to the rawlinecountfile each day also, then later, after the rest of the process finishes, all the files are cleared out to prepare for the next day.

However, since the outage last week, it only writes 0-2 out of 7 rows onto the csv file each day, not FOR EACH file (still 7).

We are stumped as to why the For Each doesn't seem to be working anymore, while the script has not been changed and the same exact script still runs as expected on the sister server, and on my local machine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd add a Start-Transcript to the beginning of the script, then let it run again and see what the transcript tells you.

Comment: Are the files hidden? If so, you're going to have to add `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: The files don't have the Hidden attribute, wish this was the answer haha

Answer (score 0):

When you were calling `Get-Content`, I believe you are trying to get the file from `C:\Temp\Files\Test\C:\Temp\Files\Test\Filename.dat`. You can use `$file.FullName` to get the full path. I suspect it was probably throwing an error and not adding the content to the file. This worked in PS 5.1.

```
$rawlineCountFile ="C:\temp\files\test\linecount"
$rawlineCountFile = $rawlineCountFile +'RawlineCount' + 'test' + '.csv'
$filePath = "C:\temp\files\test"

# do line count in files

$bak = Get-ChildItem $filePath | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".dat" } 

Try 
{ 
    Write-Output  "line_count , file_name"
    foreach ($file in $bak)
    { 
        $name = $file.name 
        $lines = @(Get-Content -Path $File.FullName).Count                  
        Write-Output "$lines , $name"  
        "$lines , $name" | Add-Content $rawlineCountFile
    } 

}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Output $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message 
}
```

Replacing just the single line I mentioned that could be an issue:

```
$rawlineCountFile ="C:\temp\files\test\linecount"
$rawlineCountFile = $rawlineCountFile +'RawlineCount' + 'test' + '.csv'
$filePath = "C:\temp\files\test"

# do line count in files

$bak = Get-ChildItem $filePath  | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".dat" } 

Try 
{ 

Write-Output  "line_count , file_name"
foreach ($file in $bak) { 

               $name = $file.name 
               $measure =(Get-Content $file.FullName | Measure-Object)              
               $lines = $measure.Count                   
               Write-Output  "$lines , $name"  

               Write-Output "$lines , $name" >> $rawlineCountFile


                } 

} catch [Exception] {
  Write-Output $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
  Write-Output $_.Exception.Message 

    }
```

Comment: $lines shows up as a blank on each row when I run this script.

Comment: Weird it works for me. Maybe try `[System.String] $Lines = @(Get-Content -Path $File.fullname).Count `

Comment: Is there any difference between:   "$lines , $name" | Add-Content $rawlineCountFile and Write-Output "$lines , $name" >> $rawlineCountFile ??

Comment: Nope. They would perform the same function. I was able to create a test directory and populate with a bunch of files. It was able to handle this and produced your desired output. If you're still having issues we might have a different version of PowerShell.

Comment: Mine says 3.0, hbu?

Comment: Version 5.1, but looking at the commands I don't think it should matter. If you're still having the issues with lines you could swap the code back that you used to calculate the number of lines.

Comment: No worries, I am able to run either line, just trying to find any reason why this issue might be happening. Differences in versions, command syntax, etc. appreciate your help!